# Is it technically incorrect to state something in this manner?

Tags: word-usage

"I want to work at the same hospital as Tom."

Tom isn't a hospital, so it might sound odd in that sense, but it's also clear that Tom isn't a hospital, and I get the feeling that this is how most people would say it in conversation.

Comment: This seems fine. It would actually be wrong if Tom were a hospital.

Comment: "the same...as" is a common English idiom.  As such, most of the people here will not even realize that, functionally, it appears odd to a foreign language learner.  You will be comforted to know that your instincts were correct; most people would say it this way in conversation and no one would confuse Tom for a hospital or even consider that a possibility (if they are a native speaker).

Comment: The sentence just truncates the phrase "as Tom works at" to remove the redundant last two words.

Comment: Or truncates 'as Tom does'

Comment: No, seriously... It is odd to him because it is an English idiom, so the words have a different contextual meaning than literal meaning... It has nothing to do with the truncated phrase... "as Tom" has a meaning to him that you are internally translating... You just don't realize that it is an idiom.

Comment: @APrejean No, it is **not** an “idiom” — at all! It is simple ellipsis of redundant and trivially recoverable information: *“I want to work at the same hospital as Tom **works at**.”*

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is the same as the following:

> I want to work at the same hospital as Tom *(does work) at.*

You have simply left off the second *works at*. If you want to reduce the ambiguity, you can leave the *does* at the end.

> I want to work at the same hospital as Tom *does*.

Either way, it would be understood that *Tom* (or even *Good Samaritan*) is not a hospital.

> I want to work at *the same hospital as* Tom.

To make matters more complex, let's say your friend had the same name as a hospital; a common name for hospitals is *Good Samaritan*.

> I want to work at *the same hospital as* Good Samaritan.

This construction (in English) still causes ambiguity, because it doesn't make sense in English to use *the same as*. It would make more sense to use *at*

> I want to work *at* Good Samaritan.